# Google+ SDK getCurrentPerson is null for about 5% of times

Tags: android, google-plus

Whenever the user is connecting, onConnected method is called, inside this method I try to fetch the user data as the documents says -

```
@Override
public void onConnected() {
  ...
  if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
  }
}
```

It works about 95% of times, but 5% of the time `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` returns null.
I Can't find any documentation about when and why it can be null. Additionally, it seems that for the same user this value can be null at one point and return the person in another. Any kind of clue about why and what should I do when the person is null will be blessed. Thanks

Comment: On the remaining 5%, what value does return `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` before the call?

Comment: Don't know, I'll need to wait until the next version release to check it

Comment: What are the scopes you are requesting?

Comment: The scopes are login and profile

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logcat?

Comment: I don't have the logcats of my app's users, I can't recreate it myself. I added log that will tell me if the user is logged in but the getCurrentPerson returns null